# print(i) for i in a returns 'none'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
`a = ('abc','bbc','ccc')`

[print(i) for i in a]` 


for i in a:
    print(i)
```

1. is `[print(i) for i in a]` is the same as   `for i in a:print(i)`
2. why `[print(i) for i in a]` will return abc bbc ccc[None, None, None], what is those none referring to

Comment: The use if `[foo for foo in bar]`, i.e. list comprehension, is for building lists; you cannot (at least should not) build a list of `print()` since it returns `None`.

Comment: *Hint:*  `print` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function writes to stdout, a special file, and returns the value `None`.

`[print(i) for i in a]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which creates a new list.

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Iterates over `a` similar to the list comprehension, but unlike the list comprehension it will not create a list. Both of them print the value `i` as they iterate over `a`

An equivalent for loop version of the list comprehension would be

```
nothing_list = []
for i in a:
    nothing_list.append(print(i))
```